# Bubble Sort (2 for loops vs 1) + Int Array to String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a homework assignment for a java class and would like some assistance. I have a bubble sort implemented into the assignment. It works wonderfully but I wrote up a version with one for loop, however, the one for loop version doesn't work. Anyone know why? This is just for kicks and giggles, not required for the assignment.

My second question is how can I convert a int array (filled with cast ints from random function) to a string array. I know a solution involves "Arrays" library, but I don't recall learning that in class and would rather use that as a last resort. Any ideas?

Here is the code if you guys are interested:

```
import static java.lang.Math.random;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int intarray[] = new int[50];
        String stringarray[] = new String[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++)
        {
            intarray[i] = (int)(1000 * random());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++)
        {
             System.out.print(intarray[i] + " ");
        }

        BubbleSort2(intarray);
        System.out.println();


        for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(intarray[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static void BubbleSort(int array[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] > array[i])
                {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void BubbleSort2(int array[])
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[(i - 1)] > array[i])
            {
                int temp = array[(i - 1)];
                array[(i - 1)] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case performance for bubble sort would be in O(n^2).

Each time you loop through the list, you are moving the maximal element to its correct position in the array (the end). In the worst case you would have to do this for each element in the list, which is why you have the outer loop. Thus ensures that you move every element to its correct location.

In `BubbleSort2`, you are essentially just moving the maximal element to the correct location, as you are carrying it position by position to the end.

As for your second question, a really simple way to do this is just first create a `String[]` of the same size:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[intarray.length];
```

Then, we can fill this array with the contents of your int array. We can do this by looping through your `int[]`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    stringArray[i] = intArray[i] + "";
}
```

This just loops through every integer in your `int[]` and then converts them to a string, and stores them in the `String[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I not understand why the bubble sort wasn't fully working! As for the string array, thanks a ton for that too! Im assuming that each element of the string array will be exactly one integer (whole number) from the int array? (Example: 500 in int[0] will be 500 in string[0])

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It just turns the number into a string, so `500` becomes `"500"`

Comment: Also, glad I could help! Don't forget to accept an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You traverse the array from start to end only once, therefore only the maximum element will be correctly sorted. In order to sort other elements, the outer cycle is necessary in bubble sort.

The simplest way of converting `int` to `String` is to concatenate it with an empty `String' like this:

```
String str = i + ""
```